# Problems with 12.10 and Mac Mini 2012

Tags: wireless, ethernet, mac-mini

When installing Ubuntu 12.10 on a Mac Mini 6,2 (2012 model), it doesn't detect any network interface. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

These instructions worked for me
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2078320&page=2